# pg-promise UPDATE returns success return code but actually not updating the table

Tags: javascript, postgresql, pg-promise, node-postgres

I am trying to update a row in pgsql table using pg-promise helpers. The query executes successfully and returns success return code. But the changes are not reflecting in the table. Should I issue COMMIT after update query or will it commit automatically in general?

```js
const condition = pgp.as.format(` WHERE key = '${value}'`, putData);
const table = new pgp.helpers.TableName({ table: 'mytab', schema: 'myschema'});
const query = pgp.helpers.update(putData, [updateCols], table) + condition;

await db.none(query).then(() => {
  status = 200;
  response['status'] = 'success';
})
.catch(error => {
  status = 500;
  response['status'] = 'failed';
  response['error'] = error.message;
  response['errorCode'] = error.code;
});
```

Comment: Unless you `BEGIN` a transaction, all statements are in auto-commit mode in Postgres.

Comment: @Bergi Okay but I dont see the updated record in the table after it returns the success return code.

Comment: Are you sure it updates the right rows? Your `WHERE` condition looks botchy. Also take a look at your database's logs.

Comment: What value does `putData.value` have? What's the type of the `key` column? Can you please print the complete `query` and post it here?

Comment: `pgp.as.format('WHERE key = '${value}'', putData);` looks wrong, you are not supposed to use ES6 strings with `format` and even less so string concatenation. Handle [query](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/global.html#event:query) event to see what you are actually executing.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi for your time to look into my question.

Comment: Thanks @vitaly-t. Two things I corrected which I am posting in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it is not updating the corresponding record is invalid input in where condition. Spaces/Null passed into WHERE condition. So it returns success without updating anything. Now the code has been corrected and it is working fine.

Secondly (it is not related to the question), I was using ES6 string format in my query formatter. As per @vitaly-t's comment, I changed it as below.

```js
pgp.as.format('WHERE key = $1', [keyValue]);
```

or

```js
pgp.as.format('WHERE key = ${keyValue}', {keyValue});
```